# How can an eigenspace have more than one dimension?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a simple question. An eigenspace is defined as the set of all the eigenvectors associated with an eigenvalue of a matrix. If $\lambda_1$ is one of the eigenvalue of matrix $A$ and $V$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$. No the eigenvector $V$ is not unique as all the multiples of this vector, $a*V$, are also eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_1$. But all these vectors have the same direction as $a*V$ ; it just means that vector $V$ is stretched or squished. So how can an eigenspace have dimension more than 1 as all the vectors corresponding to $\lambda_1$ just stay in 1 dimension and doesn't break out of it.

Comment: The eigenvectors could be linearly independent.

Comment: I  think the **Answer** answers your question. The error in your reasoning is when you say "the eigenvector coorresponding to...."; that should be "an eigenvector..."

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes...I was under the imprrssion that a vector pointing in just one direction was associated with a Eigen value and all other eigenvectors associated with this eigen value were just multiples of the first Eigen vector..so having the same direction. Did not realise  vecros pointing in different directions could be associated with a eigenvalue..till I came across eigenspace.

Comment: Even if it were true that all other eigenvectors pointed in the same direction it would still be wrong to say "the eigenvector", since there's more than one.

Comment: Yup, I agree. I have made the corrections to my initial query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the matrix $A := \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$. Its has only one eigenvalue $\lambda = 2 \in \mathbb{R}$, but the eigenspace to the eigenvalue $2$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ as 
$$A \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

and

$$A \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}= 2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} ~~.$$

Both $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ are eigenvectors, yet both are linearly independent.

---

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and an eigenvector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\lambda$, it is true that all vectors $\mu v$ (with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$) are also eigenvectors of $A$ to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. However, they are not all of them, as the example shows - different eigenvectors to an eigenvalue may be linearly independent.

Comment: So its kind of like having 2 (or more) different eigenvectors(not considering the multiples of a eigenvector) corresponding to an eigenvalue

Comment: Yes, exactly.--

Comment: @GRANZER It’s “more:” just as every nonzero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector, every nonzero linear combination of two eigenvectors that share an eigenvalue is also an eigenvector with that eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Other concrete examples from elementary geometry :

1) the matrix of projection $P$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ onto a plane, for example plane $x0y$ is such that all vectors $V$ in this plane verify $PV=1V$. The other eigenspace is generated by all vectors $V=k(0,0,1)$ which are projected onto $0$, thus verifying $PV=0V$. Therefore the eigenspace associated to $1$ is 2-dimensional, and is the whole plane $x0y$.

2) the matrix of symmetry $S$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with respect to  plane $x0y$ is such that all vectors $V$ in this plane verify as well $SV=1V$. The other eigenspace is generated by all vectors $V=k(0,0,1)$ verifying $SV=-1V$. Therefore (again) the eigenspace associated to $1$ is 2-dimensional, and is the whole plane $x0y$.